# Im trying to get the sum of every even element in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

This is what i have so far, kindly assist on where im going wrong

```
(define helper
  (lambda (lis)
    (cond
      ((null? lis) 0)
      ((null? (cdr lis)) 0)
      (else (+ (helper (cdr (cdr lis))))))))
      

(define (sumEven lis)
        (display (helper lis)))
```

This is how i call the function:

```
(define (sumEven lis)
        (display (helper lis)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the element:

```
(else (+ (car (cdr lis)) (helper (cdr (cdr lis))))))))
```